# mvc sitemap provider: menu disappears

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I am using mvcsitemap to create a menu, submenu and breadcrump for a webapp I'm developing. I am using preserveroutevalues in the xml config in order to move around my (many) parameters when rendering links. When a user starts playing around with query parameters, the menu/submenu/breadcrumb disappear after some page loads. This is not consistent and I cannot reproduce it all the time, but it happens way too ofter.

My routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "ForwardCurveDefault",
                    url: "forward-curve/{commoditycode}/{selectedyear}-{selectedmonth}-{selectedday}",
                    defaults: new {
                        controller = "ForwardCurve", action = "index",
                        selectedyear = default(DateTime).Year,
                        selectedmonth = default(DateTime).Month,
                        selectedday = default(DateTime).Day,
                        commoditycode = "none"
                    }
                );
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Consumption",
                    url: "consumption/{commoditycode}/{managedcompanyid}/{entityid}/{startyear}-{startmonth}-{startday}/{endyear}-{endmonth}-{endday}",
                    defaults: new {
                        controller = "Consumption", action = "Index",
                        // begining of current month.
                        startyear = default(DateTime).Year,
                        startmonth = default(DateTime).Month,
                        startday = default(DateTime).Day,
                        // end of current month.
                        endyear = default(DateTime).Year,
                        endmonth = default(DateTime).Month,
                        endday = default(DateTime).Day,
                        commoditycode = "none",
                        managedcompanyid = 0,
                        entityid = 0,
                    }
                );

 routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Budget",
                    url: "budget/{commoditycode}/{managedcompanyid}/{entityid}/{startyear}-{startmonth}-{startday}/{endyear}-{endmonth}-{endday}",
                    defaults: new {
                        controller = "Budget", action = "Index",
                        // begining of current month.
                        startyear = default(DateTime).Year,
                        startmonth = default(DateTime).Month,
                        startday = default(DateTime).Day,
                        // end of current month.
                        endyear = default(DateTime).Year,
                        endmonth = default(DateTime).Month,
                        endday = default(DateTime).Day,
                        commoditycode = "none",
                        managedcompanyid = 0,
                        entityid = 0,
                    }
                );
```

My sitemap

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Data Management" controller="ForwardCurve" action="Index" key="DataManagement" preservedRouteParameters="commoditycode,selectedyear,selectedmonth,selectedday">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Forward curves" controller="ForwardCurve" action="Index" key="forwardcurve" preservedRouteParameters="commoditycode,selectedyear,selectedmonth,selectedday"/>
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Consumption" controller="Consumption" action="Index" key="consumption" preservedRouteParameters="commoditycode,managedcompanyid,entityid,startyear,startmonth,startday,endyear,endmonth,endday"/>
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Budget" controller="Budget" action="Index" key="budget" preservedRouteParameters="commoditycode,managedcompanyid,entityid,startyear,startmonth,startday,endyear,endmonth,endday"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

I get a nice menu. After going back and forth to different query values, I end up in a page with a valid URL and no menu. I can see that my currentNode is null.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this out yet with [version 4.0](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=mvcsitemapprovider&prerelease=&sortOrder=package-download-count)? There have been some significant improvements in the node matching logic.